# MvvmCross complete API documentation list

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Is there a documentation of complete APIs in MVVMCross available ? My eyes didn't find one in [MvvmCross Documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/) or [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) . I was basically looking for UI-Controls available as a part of library like `MvxRecyclerView` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MvvmCross does currently not have any API docs. However, if you look in the repository, you will be able to find base Android Views here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Binding/Views

And additional from support packages here:

- RecyclerView: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross.Android.Support/V7.RecyclerView
- Core.UI: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross.Android.Support/Core.UI
- Design: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross.Android.Support/Design

Answer (score 0):

- For Designing :
  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross.Android.Support 
  here in this repository you will find all type of controls.

  - This one is Very useful for learning Mvvmcross with implementation
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DHDMNB_IeY&list=PLUGZRUcMsHDSa8j2JcJECq7OuRj6vafRe